# Black parts at edges of parent rounded element with image

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a rounded border on an element with an image as background and I am using the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/vLhpkerw/

```
<ol class="p-5 bg-gray-200">
  <li class="rounded-lg relative overflow-hidden mb-2">
      <a href="#"
          class="items-center relative z-10 flex p-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-200">
          <div class="text-gray-800">
              <div class="text-base font-normal">
                  Hello World
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
      <img class="absolute top-0 object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/1920/1080/">
</ol>
```

but it has at the edges black corners depending on the image itself, and the only way to remove it as I discovered was to remove `object-cover w-full h-full`

[image]

but I need them because in small screens it gets shrunk and shows a gray background.

is there a work around while keeping the same image appearance?

Comment: It's your gradient. You can see this if you turn off the gradient and do something like rgba(255,255,255,.05) as a background instead;

Comment: @BrianScramlin changing the gradient to static colour as in `bg-gray-200` still shows the border.